# Adding attribute to html tag?

Tags: html, dom

for internal reasons I need to attach some information to some html tag. Example:

```
<img src="mypic" mycustomvalue="abc">
```

Can I add safely like that or there is another way?

Thanks

I am currently using HTML 5

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en">
```

Comment: How are you retrieving this attribute?  Server side/Client side?

Comment: I write it with PHP, i retrive it with javascript client side

Comment: I think you can use data-* where star is your att name. <img src="mypic.jpg" data-value1="lalala" data-value2="mamama" />

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can do that.

Note that [the HTML5 standard](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/) is to prefix custom attributes with `data-`:

```
<img src="mypic" data-mycustomvalue="abc">
```

Comment: Could you also use a custom namespace? <img src="mypic" custom:mycustomvalue="abc"> ?

Comment: aww never heard of data-* :) Thanks

Comment: @John Bledsoe - No, not validly. And even if it were valid, the rules around colons in element and attribute names in HTML are so complex that I recommend steering well clear of them.

Comment: @Alohci - Thanks. I also found this relevant post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/581279/xhtml-validation-custom-namespaces-and-attributes

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set it like that, and retrieve it with :

```
document.getElementById("txtBox").getAttribute("mycustomvalue");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [getAttribute()](http://www.roseindia.net/javascript/javascript-getattribute-method.shtml), this should allow you to retrieve the value of any attribute.