# Alternative to <img> custom attributes?

Tags: html, image

If let's say I require an `<img>` to store a certain information(arbitrary snippets of metadata for JS) about that element.

```
e.g. <img class="slider-img" rel="1" src="image.png" />

So i.e in a slider, I would be able to grab that img with rel="1"
```

What are some alternatives instead of creating/misusing attributes (xbrowser && backward compatible)?

Here are some I found that's currently being used:

- HTML5, data-*
- rel attribute
- class/id attribute
- custom attributes (Dojo)

Comment: What kind of information? With title and alt, it's visible to the user but could be nice for description for example.

Comment: You mentioned Dojo, but there is also .data() for jquery.

Comment: possible duplicate of [XHTML validation, custom namespaces and attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/581279/xhtml-validation-custom-namespaces-and-attributes)

Comment: Sorry, you could understand it as information not meant to be relevant any of the current attributes. Like date-added for example. In html5 i would do it like data-date-added="12-01-11"

Comment: @Sam152 Mine is referring specifically to <img>.

Comment: I'd go for data-* attribute. Mostly because it's the way forward in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML allows for whatever you want for your elements.

Check out: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/547-jQuery-Custom-Selectors-Holy-Cow-That-Is-So-Badass-.htm

```
<img class="slider-img" rel="1" src="image.png" myOwnAttribute="MineNotYours"/>
```

It might not validate against an HTml5 validator, but it is still valid XML / HTML5. Newer browsers and older browsers work with it, they will just ignore what they don't know.

Another SO post on it: [Is it OK to add your own attributes to HTML elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305734/is-it-ok-to-add-your-own-attributes-to-html-elements)

Answer (score 0):

You can use "longdesc" attribute, it is a valid w3 code, though it is not supported by any major browsers, so you can use it to store your information.

Comment: Would unsupported attributes like that cause any issues, other than the HTML not being validated?

Comment: Nah, all browser can parse unsupported attributes like that.